# Validating OpenSSL connection certificates on IOS

Tags: ios, c, ssl, openssl

I am using OpenSSL to secure a socket connection in an IOS application. 
Currently, I am using `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` to point OpenSSL at a cacert.pem file containing root certificates, but keeping this file fresh is hard.

How does one go about integrating OpenSSL with the IOS Operating System maintained certificate store?

With a .pem file I setup OpenSSL to validate the cert like this

```
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx,"cacert.pem",NULL);
```

I don't think IOS has a convenient cacert.pem file so I think the correct approach is to perform my own validation and pass `SSL_VERIFY_NONE` to prevent OpenSSL attempting to verify the certificate, and implement some kind of check using the verify_callback?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

The disadvantage of using the iOS CA Truststore is a malicious cert can be added.

When the cert is loaded inside your binary it requires run-time hooking or reverse engineering (patching) to bypass your certificate pinning.  

The result: much harder for somebody to inspect your network traffic with a man-in-the-middle tool.

Comment: Sadly not. So we are bundling our own root certificate. Which, as you say, does have the advantage that its much harder to poison.